# What is the name of a sound track in Game of Thrones Season 6 Episode 3

Tags: game-of-thrones, soundtrack

In Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 3 in minutes around 00:40:30 when Aria Stark says:

> Which name would you like the girl speaks?

What is the name of that background sound? How can I find it?

Has anyone ever noticed how amazing it is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think identifying sound effects is on-topic here.

Comment: @Walt Since this series has [sound tracks](https://soundcloud.com/game-of-thrones-songs) which is something *related*, so I think it can't be off-topic.

Comment: This *does* sound like a trivia question. I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the background score is called  [***House of Black and White***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MU5m8fJrvQ)

Skip forward to 2:57 for this particular track